# Form_state empty after ajax callback

Tags: forms

Im struggling with my form since yesterday ... I can't find a way to retrieve values from form_state in my form function.

heres my different pieces of code :

```
    function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['mypath'] = array(
      'title' => 'Bienvenue',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('mymodule_form'),
      'access callback' => 'mymodule_checkID',
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}


function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {

        if(!empty($form_state['values']['rows'])){
            $cmdeData=$form_state['values']['rows'];
            watchdog("TEST","TEST-OUI",array(),WATCHDOG_ALERT);
        }else{
        watchdog("TEST","TEST-NON",array(),WATCHDOG_ALERT);         $cmdeExiste=checkCmde($cmdeID);
            if($cmdeExiste){
                //On récupère les données de la commande via SQL et on les stocke dans un tableau
                $cmdeData=recupCmde($cmdeID);   
            }else{
                if(isset($_GET['D1'])){
                    $cmdeData=recupIntentionCmde(explode('|', $_GET['D1']));
                }
            }
        }


      if (empty($form_state['num_lignes'])){
        if(!$cmdeExiste && (!isset($cmdeData) || empty($cmdeData[0]))) {
            $form_state['num_lignes'] = 1;
        }else{
            $form_state['num_lignes'] = count($cmdeData);
        }
      } 

      $lignes=array();
      $lignes['#tree']=TRUE;
      for ($i = 0; $i <= $form_state['num_lignes']; $i++) {

        $lignes['r'.($i+1)]=array();

        $lignes['r'.($i+1)]['ref'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#size' => 7,
          '#maxlength' => 7,
          '#required' => TRUE,
          '#default_value' => ( $i<count($cmdeData) ? $cmdeData[$i]['ref'] : '' ),
          '#disabled' => ( $i<count($cmdeData) ? TRUE : FALSE ),
        );
        $lignes['r'.($i+1)]['qte'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#size' => 3,
          '#maxlength' => 3,
          '#required' => TRUE,
          '#default_value' => ( $i<count($cmdeData) ? $cmdeData[$i]['ref'] : '' ),
          '#disabled' => ( $i<count($cmdeData) ? TRUE : FALSE ),
        );
        $lignes['r'.($i+1)]['des'] = array(
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#size' => 60,
          '#default_value' => ( $i<count($cmdeData) ? $cmdeData[$i]['ref'] : '' ),
        );
        $lignes['r'.($i+1)]['pge'] = array(
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#size' => 3,
          '#default_value' => ( $i<count($cmdeData) ? $cmdeData[$i]['ref'] : '' ),
        );
        $lignes['r'.($i+1)]['tot'] = array(
          '#type' => 'item',
          '#size' => 7,
          '#input' => FALSE,
          '#default_value' => ( $i<count($cmdeData) ? $cmdeData[$i]['ref'] : '' ),
        );

        if($i < count($cmdeData)){
            $lignes['r'.($i+1)]['btn_supp'] = array(
            '#type' => 'button',
            '#value' => t('Supprimer'),
            '#name' => t('Supprimer_'.($i+1)),
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'cmde_tlv_deleteRow_ajax_callback',
                'wrapper' => 'lignes_articles',
            ),
            );
        }else{
            $lignes['r'.($i+1)]['btn_supp'] = array(
                '#type' => 'item',
            );
        }
      }

    $form['table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'cmde_tlv_form_table',
    '#header' => array(t('Référence article'), t('Quantité'), t('Désignation'), t('Page'), t('Total')),
    'rows' => $lignes,
    '#prefix' => "<div id='lignes_articles'>",
    '#suffix' => "</div>",
  );


  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Valider la saisie',
    // '#submit' => array('cmde_tlv_submit2'),

  );


 return $form;
}


function cmde_tlv_deleteRow_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {

unset($form['table']['rows'][$form_state['triggering_element']['#parents'][1]]);

$form_state['num_lignes']--;
//$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;

return $form['table'];
}
```

From the drupal API I've read that the 'drupal_get_form' function was reseting the form_state array.

Ive tried to add a HOOK_form_alter function but ive got the same problem. heres the code :

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

    if($form_id=="mymodule_form"){


        watchdog("TEST",print_r($form_state, TRUE),array(),WATCHDOG_ALERT);
    if(!empty($form_state['values'])) watchdog("TEST","TEST2",array(),WATCHDOG_ALERT);
    }


}
```

Here what' inside the form_state array :

> Array ( [build_info] => Array ( [args] => Array ( ) [form_id] =>
>   cmde_tlv_form ) [rebuild] => [rebuild_info] => Array ( ) [redirect] =>
>   [temporary] => Array ( ) [submitted] => [executed] => [programmed] =>
>   [programmed_bypass_access_check] => 1 [cache] => [method] => post
>   [groups] => Array ( ) [buttons] => Array ( ) [input] => Array ( )
>   [num_lignes] => 2 )

Note 1 : I can't post the content of 'form_state' from the callback function, but it has 'values' and 'triggering_element' and all normal stuff

Note 2 : I did try to uncomment `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` in the callback function and did a lot of test to see if form_state was still empty (default) ... and it still was ...

Comment: Anybody maybe ?
I did search  through drupal answers or other place but didnt find anything that really helped me ...

Comment: It's not clear what problem are you experiencing exactly. BTW I see several things that seems wrong. 1/ `$cmdeID` doesn't seem to be declared. 2/ you can't modify a $form_state (neither $form) passed by reference in the ajax callback. The callback is intended to just return a form element, or an array of ajax commands.

Comment: Thanks for you reply...
$cmdeID is declared but not display here.
I could alter the form and delete my row when rebuilding the form but I can't have access to form_state ...
What I can't figure out is that in the example module fro dripal developers, I can see a lot of examples of form build like mine (using 'drupal_get_form' and testing for presence of someting specific in $form_state to rebuild differently when after ajax callback) ... 

Its really bothering ...

Answer (score 1):

I did find why my **$form_state** array was reset: The **required** attribute was the problem. Adding `'#limit_validation_errors' => array()` to my delete button did the trick.